# Find all records based on quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, datepart

I have a table named Accidents. I am tying to return all records based on which quarter the reported date is in.
This is how the table looks like:

```
Accidents Table

| acc_id  | acc_descrip |reported_date|
| 1       | collision   |2019-20-01
| 2       | hit and run |2019-08-01
| 3       | collision   |2019-10-06
```

So this works in terms of giving me all the records in the table and which quarter and year they fall in. But I want to pass a parameter of year only and get the results of that year of records and the quarter which it falls in?

```
alter PROCEDURE AccidentByQuarter
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN MONTH(ReportedDate) IN (1,2,3)  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(ReportedDate) - 1) + 'Q3'
WHEN MONTH(ReportedDate) IN (4,5,6)  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(ReportedDate) - 1) + 'Q4'
WHEN MONTH(ReportedDate) IN (7,8,9)  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(ReportedDate) - 0) + 'Q1'
WHEN MONTH(ReportedDate) IN (10,11,12) THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(ReportedDate) - 0) + 'Q2'
END AS Quarter  FROM Incident
END
```

Comment: Could probably use [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in your `WHERE` clause depending on how you have things set up. Personally I'd just accept a @startDate and @endDate parameter and then handle the *quarter* logic inside the proc. When does the quarter start and end? Is it FY or CY? Etc...

Comment: What kind of a result do you expect? Sample result set would be helpful.

Comment: @scsimon Q1: Jan-Mar, Q2:Apr-May etc

Comment: @RasanjanaN I want to pass a year and get the records for that year only and the quarter which it falls in

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not a big issue, I would do:

```
alter procedure AccidentByMonth (
    @ReportedDate int
)
AS
Begin
    select *
    from Incident
    where month(ReportedDate) / 4 = @ReportedDate / 4
End;
```

That is a little bit arcane -- because the values start at 1 and not 0.  It is probably more readable to do:

```
    where (month(ReportedDate) - 1) / 4 = (@ReportedDate - 1) / 4
```

Or:

```
   where datepart(quarter, RepertedDate) = (@ReportedDate - 1) / 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution.

This query dynamically computes the dates of quarter start and end for the given `@ReportedDate` parameter. Hence it will take advantage of an index on column `ReportedDate`, since no computation happens on the left side of the comparison operators.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE AccidentByMonth (@ReportedDate int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Incident 
    WHERE 
        ReportedDate >= DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, @ReportedDate), 0) 
        AND ReportedDate < DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, @ReportedDate) + 1, 0)) 
END
```

Comment: I tried executing with different numbers to represent the month but didnt get any reults.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. According your parameter name @ReportDate I assume that is date as integer (20190207 = 2019-02-07). I use CONVERT function because your function param is INT.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE AccidentByMonth
    (
        @ReportedDate int
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM   Incident
        WHERE  DATEPART(QUARTER, ReportedDate) = DATEPART(QUARTER, CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ReportedDate,101)));
    END;
```

Comment: Reported date is actually datetime. With the example procedure I gave I could just pass an integer 1-12 to get incidents for that particular month